# Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraExpandableGroupBox showing error

Tags: vb.net, infragistics

I have VB.net application in which Infragistics dll is showing error. I tried to get its dll but its not seems available anywhere.

its shwoing the following error while trying build the application

```
Exception occurred creating type 'Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraExpandableGroupBox, Infragistics2.Win.Misc.v7.2, Version=7.2.20072.61, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb' System.ComponentModel.LicenseException    E:\CONTRIBUTION MANAGER\Contribution Manager\Win764\ContributionManager\My Project\licenses.licx
```

Anybody who have any idea about this dll please help me out!!

Comment: looks like your license isn't valid

Comment: @DavidSdot how can i get the licensed one?

Comment: http://www.infragistics.com/how-to-buy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this helps, just set the build action on your license.licx to None.